# Google App Engine - Suddenly started getting Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Suddenly started getting this warning in GAE without making any changes to app, it has been continuously occurring ever since, although the app is working fine.

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Haven't made any changes since, but would like to know why this appeared all of a sudden. curl extension is enabled, and currently being used.

Answer (score 1):

Google have been performing some kind of runtime upgrade which led to this issue.

Their known issues page says it has been happening since "10 May 2017, 12:00AM PDT".

It isn't on https://status.cloud.google.com/ yet, but it is in the Support portal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved as of may-25-17. See the public issue here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38371234